# How to sustainably organise user schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a user which should have the following fields and currently has following schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      lowercase: true,
    },
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false }, // whether user has confirmed his email
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    password: { type: String, required: true, minLength: 6 }, // object with next two included?
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    passwordResetToken: String, 
    roles: [{ type: 'String' }], // Array of strings?
    username: { type: String, required: false },
    token: [{ type: String, required: false }], // used to send verification token via email
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

So yes, what is the world's default standard for organising user schemas. This schema's fields are pretty common, right?

Comment: What is your doubt here?

Comment: What is the right organisation? I mean advise from experienced developers.